# How to compare and flag colsest string rows

Tags: pandas, group-by, pandas-groupby, transform

My goal is to detect the consecutive rows based on `res` column are equal by using `transform()` or `apply()` functions.

**My dataframe:**

```
data = [[111, 123, "aa", 0], 
        [111, 124, "bb", 1], 
        [111, 125, "bb", 2],
        [111, 126, "cc", 0],
        [111, 127, "dd", 1],
        [111, 128, "cc", 2],
        [222, 133, "xx", 1],
        [222, 134, "yy", 2],
        [222, 135, "zz", 0], 
        [222, 136, "zz", 1],] 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ["uuid", "foo_id", "res", "num"])
```

**What I m looking for:**

```
111, 123, "aa", 0, 0 
111, 124, "bb", 1, 1 
111, 125, "bb", 2, 1
111, 126, "cc", 0, 0
111, 127, "dd", 1, 0
111, 128, "cc", 2, 0
222, 133, "xx", 1, 0
222, 134, "yy", 2, 0
222, 135, "zz", 0, 1
222, 136, "zz", 1, 1
```

**I used:**

```
df['flag'] = df.groupby('uuid')['res'].tranform(lambda x:  1 if x == x.shift(-1) else 0)
```

**Return:**

```
*ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().*
```

Comment: Duplicated, or sequential within group. For instance does [aa, bb, aa] within a group consider aa flagged or not?

Comment: What @ALollz says, consider you have 2 values duplicated in a single group, what do you want to return in such case.

Comment: @anky You are right, a solution without the `duplicate()` function would be fine

Comment: can you add more duplicates in a group and show what you want? for group 111 , if you have 2 duplicates `aa,aa,xx,xx,yy`, do you want `1,2,1,2,1`? or `0,0,1,1,2` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, You can try with `series.duplicated` for each group:

```
f = lambda x: (x.eq(x.shift()) | x.eq(x.shift(-1))).astype(int)
df['flag'] = df.groupby('uuid')['res'].transform(f)
```

---

```
print(df)

    uuid  foo_id res  num  flag
0    111     123  aa    0     0
1    111     124  bb    1     1
2    111     125  bb    2     1
3    111     126  cc    0     0
4    111     127  dd    1     0
5    111     128  ee    2     0
6    111     129  dd    3     0
7    222     133  xx    1     0
8    222     134  yy    2     0
9    222     135  zz    0     1
10   222     136  zz    1     1
```

Comment: I looking to flag and compare the closest rows, I have updated my dataframe to make it clear to you.

Comment: @AdilBlanco didnt realise you updated the question, can you replace `f` with `f = lambda x: (x.eq(x.shift()) | x.eq(x.shift(-1))).astype(int)` and check, edited my answer